# sending keypresses to a process using nircmd

Tags: batch, nircmd

I'm trying to use nircmdc to send a keypress to a background process (without bringing it to front).

More precisely, i'm tring to send Ctrl+Shift+S to notepad++.exe:

```
nircmdc win postmsg process notepad++.exe WM_KEYDOWN VK_CTRL 0
nircmdc win postmsg process notepad++.exe WM_KEYDOWN VK_SHIFT 0x40000000
nircmdc win postmsg process notepad++.exe WM_KEYDOWN VK_S 0x40000000
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a set of combination of keys in nircmd you can use 
`nircmd sendkeypresss keyCombination`
e.g. to open task manager using nircmd use
`nircmd sendkeypress ctrl+shift+esc`
so try using nircmd sendkeypress ctrl+s
for more help you can see [nircmd](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/sendkeypress.html)